# Conductance per unit length

Tags: conductance

I want to measure the conductance per unit length of a transmission line consisting of two parallel wires. Below you see a possible set up with an ohm meter and the transmission line.

[image]

Would it be possible to measure a resistance between the two wires?
If yes I could take the reciprocal and determine the condutance per unit length.

Comment: Have you tried to take a reading?

Comment: The conductance per unit length is not the reciprocal of resistance per unit length. The conductance refers to the shunt leakage conductance between the conductors.

Comment: @Kaswechiha who mentioned "resistance per unit length" other than you?

Comment: @Andyaka no I don't, the cable is far away before I go there I wanted to be sure. But I honestly think that this won't work. By the way the cable is probably more than a kilometer long

Comment: G may be so low that even on a kilometre of cable your ohm meter may not register anything other than an open-circuit. Because of that, it is regarded as "not significant" compared to R, C and L except when the frequency rises above 100 MHz. At this high frequency (and above), G represents the emerging dielectric losses and these are just not seen at DC.

Comment: A plastic insulated cable when dry, even 1 km long, will have an unmeasurable shunt conductance. A cable with damp porous insulation, or being connected through damp connection boxes may have a very low shunt conductance.

Answer (score -1):

> Would it be possible to measure a resistance between the two wires?

Unless you can somehow deliberately short-circuit the other side of the transmission lines, you will not be able to measure the total (DC) resistance of these wires and as a result the resistance per length. Even if there is some kind of parasitic path between the two wires, I think it is safe assume there is no way to find out *where* it occurs, and *how large* the resistance of that leakage path is without prior knowledge, making the problem effectively unsolvable.

You may have a better chance of characterizing these transmission lines (if that is your ultimate goal) using a [Time-Domain Reflectometer (TDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer). I think it's safe to assume they're pretty expensive though, and they require some knowledge about transmission lines and voltage/current waves to interpret (I've only built and characterized the setup of a TDR in an academic setting).

Comment: Sven, the OP is trying to measure G and not R.

Comment: @Andyaka I assumed he might still be interested in whether or not it was possible to measure \$R\$. You pretty much answered \$G\$ yourself in the comment section (on that note, please post it as an answer :-) ).